# How to write a servlet program which consume both XML and JSON?

Tags: java, json, xml, servlets

I am writing a servlet program, which aim to accept both xml and json, my request in json is this,

```
{"Symbol":["OLM","ASC"]}
```

and it is working well.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection connection = null;
        
         BufferedReader reader1 = request.getReader();
         
         StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
         
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
             jb.append(line);
         }
        
         String str = jb.toString();
      
         
      
         JSONObject obj2 = null;
        try {
            obj2 = new JSONObject(str);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray array = null;
        try {
            array = (JSONArray) obj2.get("Symbol");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I know that it is working for json because of I am casting the obtained string(in my case str) to JSONObject, but if I want to accept XML also and obtain Symbol from it, how to change this code?
Thanks in advance

Iam updating my question,

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    
    
    if(request.getHeader("content-type")=="application/json") {
        System.out.println("json ");
        Symbol symbolContainerFromJson = objectMapper.readValue(request.getReader(), Symbol.class);
        System.out.println(symbolContainerFromJson.getSymbolName());

    } 
    
    else if (request.getHeader("content-type")=="application/xml") {
        System.out.println("xml");
        Symbol symbolContainerFromXml = new XmlMapper().readValue(request.getReader(), Symbol.class);

        System.out.println(symbolContainerFromXml.getSymbolName()); 
    }
```

But it is not entering both the loops, kindly help

Comment: You should probably use the html content-negotiation headers (Content-Type) on the web request and pass it to a designated handler.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Actually it is possible to send xml but at the server side how to retrive the symbol form XML request? JSON is okay because I can directly change received string to JSONObject like this obj2 = new JSONObject(str);   but inorder to accept xml also how to change the code at server? @NicoVanBelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most robust way to deserialize is by creating the data structure in the back-end and let a framework like Jackson do the heavy lifting.

So we first create our object representation that we expect in either XML or JSON. No magic, it's just a POJO. I add a JsonProperty annotation because you expect Symbol upper-case and I hate upper-case fields in Java.

```java
public class SymbolContainer {

    @JsonProperty("Symbol")
    private List<String> symbol;

    public List<String> getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

Then I use a Jackson Object/Xml mapper to transform the content from the request body to an in-memory object.

```java
if(contentTypeIsJson(request.getHeader("content-type"))) {
    SymbolContainer symbolContainerFromJson = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"Symbol\":[\"OLM\",\"ASC\"]}", SymbolContainer.class);
    System.out.println(symbolContainerFromJson.getSymbol()); // [OLM, ASC]

} else if (contentTypeIsXml(request.getHeader("content-type"))) {
    SymbolContainer symbolContainerFromXml = new XmlMapper().readValue("<root>\n" +
                "   <Symbol>\n" +
                "      <element>OLM</element>\n" +
                "      <element>ASC</element>\n" +
                "   </Symbol>\n" +
                "</root>", SymbolContainer.class);

    System.out.println(symbolContainerFromXml.getSymbol()); // [OLM, ASC]
}
```

This using only these three Jackson dependencies

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note that these ObjectMappers can be configured. If you are only interested in a part of the request (eg Symbol) and want to ignore the rest of the passed object, best to configure your ObjectMapper like so, which lets you ignore unmapped fields.

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I am a beginner and your answer helped me a lot for understanding the concept as well as finding answer @NicoVanBelle

Comment: Hello sir, I updated my code like your suggestion, but it is not entering both the loops , why? kindly help me @NicoVanBelle

Comment: @sam
1. Use `equals` for string comparison. 
2. Make sure request.getHeader("content-type") is not null because the header could be case-sensitive
3. Perhaps it's also best to use contains instead of equals like `request.getHeader("Content-Type").contains("xml")` because the header can be `application/xml` but also `text/xml`